# Xcode 4.2.1 installation problem

Tags: xcode

After I opened the dmg file there's an app called **Install Xcode** which asks me to agree. After entering administrator's password, it starts installing but then it stops and says it encountered an error and to consult `/var/log/install.log`.

Comment: What version of OS X are you trying to install this on?

Comment: Well, what did it have to say in the install.log file?

Comment: @kenorb, I am not the author of the OP, user142164 is.

Comment: @user142164 Please paste the full error or screenshot.

Comment: @user3439894 Similarities are too confusing:)